# Tikz right-angle edges between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

In the example below I'd like to have angled edges which just go vertically and horizontally.
My aim is to get the edges like in this image (the rounded edges are not a must) [image: BPMN image]:

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning, shapes.symbols,shapes.callouts,patterns}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    pre/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt,>=stealth',semithick},
    post/.style={->,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth',semithick}
    ]

\node[draw](start){start};

\node[draw, right=of start] (split) {+}
            edge[pre](start);

\node[draw, right=of split](pricedb){PriceDB}
    edge[pre](split);

\node[draw, below=of pricedb](stockdb){StockDB}
    edge[pre](split);

\node[draw, above=of pricedb](orderpage){OrderPage}
    edge[pre](split);   

\node[draw,right=of pricedb](join){+}
    edge[pre](pricedb)
    edge[pre](stockdb)
    edge[pre](orderpage);

\node[draw, right=of join](invoice){invoiceservice}
    edge[pre](join);

\node(silent)[right=of invoice]{}
    edge[<-,shorten <=1pt,>=stealth',semithick, dashed](invoice);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

with draw it's simple

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning, shapes.symbols,shapes.callouts,patterns}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    pre/.style={=stealth',semithick},
    post/.style={->,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth',semithick}
    ]

\node[draw](start){start};

\node[draw, right=of start] (split) {+}
            edge[pre](start);

\node[draw, right=of split](pricedb){PriceDB}
    edge[pre](split);

\node[draw, below=of pricedb](stockdb){StockDB};
\node[draw, above=of pricedb](orderpage){OrderPage};   
\node[draw,right=of pricedb](join){+}
    edge[pre](pricedb);
\node[draw, right=of join](invoice){invoiceservice}
    edge[pre](join);

 \draw[post,rounded corners=5pt] (orderpage)-|(join)  ;   
 \draw[post,rounded corners=5pt] (stockdb)-|(join)  ;   
 \draw[post,rounded corners=5pt] (split) |- (orderpage);
  \draw[post,rounded corners=5pt] (split) |- (stockdb);

\node(silent)[right=of invoice]{}
    edge[=stealth',semithick, dashed](invoice);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: liens]

Answer (score 8):

Actually you can do that with `edge` instead of `\draw`: Just add

```
\tikzset{
    -|/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
    |-/.style={to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
}
```

somewhere, then you can use `edge[-|]` and `edge[|-]`. (Of course you can replace them with other names like “hv” or “vh” for “horizontal-vertical” etc, if you still want to use the `-|`/`|-` arrow heads somewhere.)

Your code will then look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.symbols,shapes.callouts,patterns}


\begin{document}    
\tikzset{
    -|/.style={to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}},
    |-/.style={to path={|- (\tikztotarget)}},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        pre/.style={<-,shorten <=1pt,>=stealth',semithick},
        post/.style={->,shorten >=1pt,>=stealth',semithick}
    ]

    \node[draw](start){start};

    \node[draw, right=of start] (split) {+}
        edge[pre](start);

    \node[draw, right=of split](pricedb){PriceDB}
        edge[pre](split);

    \node[draw, below=of pricedb](stockdb){StockDB}
        edge[pre,-|](split);

    \node[draw, above=of pricedb](orderpage){OrderPage}
        edge[pre,-|](split);

    \node[draw,right=of pricedb](join){+}
        edge[pre](pricedb)
        edge[pre,|-](stockdb)
        edge[pre,|-](orderpage);

    \node[draw, right=of join](invoice){invoiceservice}
        edge[pre](join);

    \node(silent)[right=of invoice]{}
        edge[<-,shorten <=1pt,>=stealth',semithick, dashed](invoice);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about when you want `-|-` or `|-|`? Is there some smart way to achieve this?